# Wrapping an existing shortcode with a new one

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a wordpress plugin that extends an existing plugin's behavior.

The existing plugin defines a shortcode named `[original]` and I define a shortcode named `[wrapper]` that adds some functionality, but basically behaves the same.

This is the code I wrote:

```
function wrapper_shortcode($atts,$content)
{
    //Do something...
    return do_shortcode("[original]$content[/original]");
}
add_shortcode( 'wrapper', 'wrapper_shortcode' );
```

My question is, how do I pass the attributes (`$atts`) next to the `[original]` shortcode, and is there a better way to do this than to call the `do_shortcode()` function ?

Comment: best way is to modify the original shortcode and make sure the output is wrap with ```do_shortcode``` function then you can put any shortcode inside it, its best if the original shortcode has some filter or hooks

Comment: Changing the original shortcode is not an option, since any changes to the plugin code will be overridden when the original plugin gets updated

Comment: you can modify the original shortcode by removing it using ```remove shortcode``` and adding it again  using the same shortcode tag but running different function, but then you need to update your custom function once the original function is modified, If that still won't work, then you need to use regex to too look for the the original shortcode, extract its attribute and re-run it inside your function with some modification, its not that hard but I'm not good at regex so I can't give you an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to grab all shortcode parameters and blindly pass them from `wrapper` over to your `original` shortcode.

I would **not** recommend passing parameters over without proper validation.

You have a few options:

1. As silver suggests, remove `original` and replace it with your own modified version (since you can't update the plugin). Update it after each release of the plugin.
2. Add the parameters you wish to validate and pass through. and post it back in the return.

---

**NOT RECOMMENDED** - Just because you can; doesn't mean you should.

It does sound like you want to do something like the following - If you were to do this, you really could be asking for trouble, unless you validate each attribute as it comes through:

```
function wrapper_shortcode($atts, $content) {
    $o_shortcode_atts = " ";
    foreach ($atts as $key_att => $val_att) {

        // Validate $key_att and $val_att here - FOR SECURITY!!!

        $o_shortcode_atts = $o_shortcode_atts . " ".$key_att."=\"".$val_att."\" ";
    }
    trim($o_shortcode_atts," ");

    // Do something...

    return do_shortcode("[original".$o_shortcode_atts."]".$content."[/original]");
}
```

**WARNING - THIS COULD BE ASKING FOR TROUBLE IF YOU DO NOT VALIDATE**

Comment: Why is passing the attributes blindly asking for trouble ? the user could use `[original a=1]` or `[wrapper a=1]` anyway, so why do I need to do any validation of the input ? it is supposed to be already covered in the `[original]` shortcode code

Comment: that is true... but you don't know 100% - [original] may be validating the unknown parameters (hence the word blindly - if you did know what was being parsed, it wouldn't be unknown and quantified)..For all we know, [original] may take a parameter and plug it directly into a DB query - we just don't know. In the example provided, you are pulling in some arbitrary user input, and then effectively "redisplaying it" for another shortcode to process - You could potentially introduce some kind of injection vector, or cross site scripting issue. I've just always been taught to CHECK all input

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/ https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/keeping-web-users-safe-by-sanitizing-input-data/